# SQL Query for getting PropertyTypeName of an object in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: sql, enterprise-architect

I get the PropertyTypeName of an object using the following code,

```
typename = eaElement.PropertyTypeName
```

What would be the equivalent SQL query to get the same?

Tried looking up t_objectproperties,t_objects,t_attributes etc tables. Couldn't find what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PropertyTypeName of a property or Type is hidden in EA through the `PDATA1` column.

That column contains the `ea_guid` of the type element.

```
select o.name as partName, ot.Name as TypeName
from t_object o
inner join t_object ot on ot.ea_guid = o.PDATA1
where o.ea_guid = '<replace by guid of part>'
```